# Statistics of Instant Runoff Voting

Tags: voting-systems, statistics

Has anyone published statistics on how many recounts (i.e. runoffs) are necessary for resolving an [instant runoff election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting), versus the number of candidates?

Data from real life would be good, but simulations would also be interesting.

Also of interest: how often do ties occur?

Comment: A link to some explanation about what is Runoff Voting would be nice.

Comment: @Evargalo there's also a CGP Grey [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Y3jE3B8HsE).

Comment: why would more than one runoff be required? the spanish senate is elected via IRV if you need data.

Comment: @CptEric I understood that as long as no candidate has more than 50% of the votes, the votes of the worst candidate get redistributed (equivalent to a runoff). So with 8 candidates, there could be up to 7 runoffs, right ?

Comment: @S.Chevalier When you only want to elect one person and don't require a minimum number of votes for the winning candidate, then you can stop after the 6th runoff, because then you are left with two candidates, one of them (hopefully) having more votes than the other. When one needs a minimum number of votes, then you might need to do a 7th runoff to check if the last candidate reached it.

Comment: @CptEric from what I gather, the Spanish senate is elected with [multiple non-transferable vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurality-at-large_voting), not IRV. On the other hand, it seems that the Australian House of representatives does use IRV. Do you know where I can find data on these elections ?

Comment: Actually, I found [these] datasets from the 2004 Australian house of representatives election, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if someone has already done some similar work.

Comment: Two other things to remember.  Firstly, it will depend on how many "major" parties there are.  More major parties will imply a smaller primary vote, and thus more rounds than a two-major-party system with as many candidates.  Secondly, some countries (ex. Ireland) will skip over unnecessary runoffs when it's mathematically impossible for the last place candidate to escape that position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran the following analysis based on the 2016 House of Representatives Election in Australia.  It shows a slight correlation, however it also shows a significant standard deviation within electorates with the same number of candidates.

[image: IRV Analysis]

Most candidate counts had at least one electorate decided on first preferences, and most had at least one decided on two-candidate preferred.

For the benefit of those unable to see the chart:

- 3 candidates: 1.00 counts (average based on 1 electorate)
- 4 candidates: 1.82 counts (11 electorates)
- 5 candidates: 2.24 counts (34 electorates)
- 6 candidates: 3.33 counts (36 electorates)
- 7 candidates: 4.75 counts (28 electorates)
- 8 candidates: 4.41 counts (17 electorates)
- 9 candidates: 7.62 counts (8 electorates)
- 10 candidates: 5.88 counts (8 electorates)
- 11 candidates: 10.0 counts (7 electorates)

Source of raw data: [Australian Electoral Commission](http://results.aec.gov.au/20499/Website/HouseDownloadsMenu-20499-Csv.htm).

Method: The electorates were grouped based on the number of candidates nominated in the 2016 election.  The number of counts required for a candidate to reach 50% of the vote was determined for each electorate, and then the average, min/max and standard deviation was calculated within each group.  In Australia, each count results in the elimination of exactly one candidate.  For the sake of avoiding ambiguity, the first count is the first-preference, and the second count is the first runoff.

EDIT: Breakdown table to supplement the above:

```
                     CANDIDATES
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  1|   |   | 1 | 6 | 17| 11| 5 | 5 |   | 3 |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  2|   |   |   | 1 | 3 | 2 |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  3|   |   |   | 4 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  4|   |   |   |   | 11| 4 | 2 | 2 |   |   |   |
C  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
O 5|   |   |   |   |   | 16| 3 | 1 |   |   |   |
U  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
N 6|   |   |   |   |   |   | 17| 2 | 1 |   |   |
T  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
S 7|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 6 | 1 |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  8|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 6 | 1 |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  9|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 4 |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 10|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 7 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Great answer ! So *all* the 11-candidate electorates needed 11 runoffs. Do you know if that's a coincidence ?

Comment: What do the distributions of counts look like for the >10 electorate groups look like? I'd be interested in seeing the electorates that decided on first preference separated out

Comment: Also, would you consider publishing the code for this analysis ?

Comment: @S.Chevalier So all seven of the electorates that had 11 candidates had relatively strong third-place candidates (mostly from the Greens, but Family First and One Nation were among them).  But that can be said with a number of other electorates as well, so I'd put it down to coincidence.

Comment: @Caleth I've posted the electorate-level summaries [here](https://pastebin.com/pSXHUWsr), if you'd like to play around with it.

Comment: @JoeC Thanks! The theory I have is that there are ~two populations of electorates, one where there is a clear winner in round one, and one where *most* other candidates are eliminated before a winner emerges

Comment: @Caleth I just edited my answer to provide a more fine-grained breakdown, and it definitely seems to support that theory.